# How to structure routing in react router dom without using the 'exact' parameter?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to set up modal routing using react router. For it to work the underlying route behind that which is displaying the modal cannot have an 'exact' parameter.

Is there a way to maintain the current routing functionality shown below, but without using 'exact' on the Home route? (the Home component will be creating the modal routes) ie. Is there another way to have this routing in react router (using more Switches etc?) whereby I can omit the 'exact' from the Home Route and everything will still route correctly?

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <MainLayout>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
            <Route exact path='/login' component={Login}/>
            <Route exact path='/buy/:id' component={View}/>
            <PrivateRoute exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard}/>
        </MainLayout>
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

For example, if I remove the 'exact' parameter from Home Route in the above code the Login component will appear on the Home page, when it should be on a separate page/route.

Is this possible?
Cheers, Matt

Comment: make the home route the last, then you can remove exact from all the routes

Comment: @kenn Thanks for the reply. Still the same issue, it just renders the login component first, and the home component below it. I tried no components with 'exact', all components apart from the Home with exact, but still the same issue

Comment: Every route will have a `/` in it so whatever component you define at that path will always render without `exact`. Move your `Home` component to a path with a unique prefix then you won't need `exact`.

Answer (score 0):

React router returns the first component that matches with url even if it is matching partially
So both '/login' and '/' will match the first url partially and fully and return Home component, which is not true.
I think changing order of routes will work in your case

```
<Switch>  
    <MainLayout>  
        <Route path='/login' component={Login}/>  
        <Route path='/buy/:id' component={View}/>  
        <PrivateRoute path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard}/>  
        <Route path='/' component={Home}/>  
    </MainLayout>  
</Switch>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Please see my comment above, both the login and home components get rendered on the same page when I click on the login link